# Can XAMPP and mysql both exit on mac?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my mac, and it has xampp's mysql, and I can run it.

Now I download mysql from Orcal, but I find some problem adding path.

When I run
mysql -u root -p
[image: the wrong message shows:]

I think it might because of the path, the origin path shows like
[image]

I try to replace the path of xampp , I replace it by mysql path,
[image]

but it still wrong.
So, how can I run mysql on my mac without deleting XAMPP?

Comment: why do you need mysql after installing XAMPP?

Comment: I don't know the Mac internals but you can have as many MySQL servers as you want, as long as they listen to different IP+port combinations. However, unless you explicitly want to support different versions (which is likely not the case) I suggest you uninstall all servers except the one you actually want to use.